# Microsoft Graph Client - Update Planner Task

Tags: c#, api, client

Can anyone get this Microsoft example to work?  I know its not an authentication issue as I can perform other CRUD operations with the graph client.  When I try to update the plan task details I get the error:

The request is invalid:
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: qualifiedName:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/plannertaskdetails-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

```
    // Code snippets are only available for the latest version. Current version is 5.x

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

var requestBody = new PlannerTaskDetails
{
    PreviewType = PlannerPreviewType.NoPreview,
    References = new PlannerExternalReferences
    {
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {
                "http%3A//developer%2Emicrosoft%2Ecom" , new 
                {
                    OdataType = "microsoft.graph.plannerExternalReference",
                    Alias = "Documentation",
                    PreviewPriority = " !",
                    Type = "Other",
                }
            },
            {
                "https%3A//developer%2Emicrosoft%2Ecom/en-us/graph/graph-explorer" , new 
                {
                    OdataType = "microsoft.graph.plannerExternalReference",
                    PreviewPriority = "  !!",
                }
            },
            {
                "http%3A//www%2Ebing%2Ecom" , null
            },
        },
    },
    Checklist = new PlannerChecklistItems
    {
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {
                "95e27074-6c4a-447a-aa24-9d718a0b86fa" , new 
                {
                    OdataType = "microsoft.graph.plannerChecklistItem",
                    Title = "Update task details",
                    IsChecked = true,
                }
            },
            {
                "d280ed1a-9f6b-4f9c-a962-fb4d00dc50ff" , new 
                {
                    OdataType = "microsoft.graph.plannerChecklistItem",
                    IsChecked = true,
                }
            },
            {
                "a93c93c5-10a6-4167-9551-8bafa09967a7" , null
            },
        },
    },
};
var result = await graphClient.Planner.Tasks["{plannerTask-id}"].Details.PatchAsync(requestBody, (requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.Headers.Add("Prefer", "return=representation");
    requestConfiguration.Headers.Add("If-Match", "W/\"JzEtVGFzayAgQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAWCc=\"");
});
```